# How do you assign groups to larger groups dpylr

Tags: r, dplyr, data-munging

I would like to assign groups to larger groups in order to assign them to cores for processing. I have 16 cores.This is what I have so far

`test<-data_extract%>%group_by(group_id)%>%sample_n(16,replace = TRUE)`

This takes staples OF 16 from each group.

This is an example of what I would like the final product to look like (with two clusters),all I really want is for the same group id to belong to the same cluster as a set number of clusters

```
________________________________
balance   | group_id |  cluster|
454452    | a        |  1      |
5450441   | a        |  1      |
5444531   | b        |  1      |
5404051   | b        |  1      |
5404501   | b        |  1      |
5404041   | b        |  1      |
544251    | b        |  1      |
254252    | b        |  1      |
541254    | c        |  2      |
54123254  | d        |  1      |
542541    | d        |  1      |
5442341   | e        |  2      |
541       | f        |  1      |
________________________________
```

Comment: Is this your expected output or input?

Comment: This is my expected output

Comment: ok, sorry, without a input example, it is difficult to test

Comment: The very best would be to provide input, actual output, and expected output.

Comment: The input would be the data provided without the column 'Cluster' (sorry for the confusion)

Comment: We really need a reproducible example to help you. If your dataset is not too big, please write the output of `dput(data_extract)`. Else, select relevant columns and lines before (`dplyr::select` and `dplyr::filter`).

Comment: This is the problem, my actual data contains a couple million rows and each group contains from a few hundred to a few thousand

Comment: I suggest you to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example , in order to make a reproducible example

Comment: `data_extract %>% select(group_id, balance, clusterOrAnotherColumn) %>% head(20) %>% dput`. If the head does not contain enough groups, select some lines that do. Give us whatever we can use as input to test some answers.

Answer (score 0):

test<-data%>%group_by(group_id)%>%  mutate(group = sample(1:16,1))

Comment: How is this question different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59310398/how-to-assign-a-number-between-1-and-n-in-r-to-rows/59310651#59310651

Comment: Apparently it was not, I think describing the issue in terms of groups ended up being confusing, when in reality it does not matter because group_by ends up treating groups as if they are the same row