# How to assign a number between 1 and n in R to rows?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to assign individual in my data randomly to a group numbered 1 though 3, how would I do this? ( a DPLYR Solution is preferred), individuals (rows with the same id# must be in the same group)

```
_______________________
id #      | group_id |  
454452    | 1        |  
5450441   | 2        |  
5444531   | 3        |  
5444531   | 3        |  
5404501   | 1        |  
5404041   | 2        |  
5404041   | 2        |  
254252    | 3        |  
541254    | 2        |  
_______________________
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution might be:

`df <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(group_id = sample(1:3,1))`

which (using set.seed(12345)) resulted in:

```
       id group_id
1  454452        3
2 5450441        1
3 5444531        2
4 5444531        2
5 5404501        2
6 5404041        3
7 5404041        3
8  254252        2
9  541254        2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

```
library(dplyr)

df <-
  tibble(ids = c(100, 200, 200, 300, 300, 400))

distinct_ids <- 
  df %>% 
  select(ids) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  mutate(group_num = sample.int(3, size = nrow(.), replace = TRUE))

df %>% 
  left_join(distinct_ids, by = "ids")

# A tibble: 6 x 2
    ids group_num
  <dbl>     <int>
1   100         3
2   200         1
3   200         1
4   300         3
5   300         3
6   400         2
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R we could sample the `factor`ized `"id"` and display them `as.numeric`.

```
set.seed(42)  # for sake of reproducibility
dat <- transform(dat, group_id=as.numeric(factor(id, levels=sample(unique(dat$id)))))
dat

#        id         X1         X2          X3 group_id
# 1  454452 -1.1045994  0.0356312  1.93557177        1
# 2 5450441  0.5390238  1.3149588  1.72323080        5
# 3 5444531  0.5802063  0.9781675  0.35840206        6
# 4 5444531 -0.6575028  0.8817912  0.30243092        6
# 5 5404501  1.5548955  0.4822047 -0.39411451        7
# 6 5404041 -1.1876414  0.9657529  0.78814062        2
# 7 5404041  0.1518129 -0.8145709  0.67070383        2
# 8  254252 -1.0861326  0.2839578 -0.94918081        4
# 9  541254  1.6133728 -0.1616986  0.03613574        3
```

#### Data

```
dat <- structure(list(id = c(454452L, 5450441L, 5444531L, 5444531L, 
5404501L, 5404041L, 5404041L, 254252L, 541254L), X1 = c(-1.10459944068306, 
0.539023801893912, 0.580206320853481, -0.657502835154674, 1.55489554810057, 
-1.18764140164182, 0.151812914504533, -1.08613257605253, 1.61337280035418
), X2 = c(0.0356311982051355, 1.31495884897891, 0.978167526364279, 
0.881791226863203, 0.482204688262918, 0.965752878105794, -0.814570938270238, 
0.283957806364306, -0.161698647607024), X3 = c(1.93557176599585, 
1.72323079854894, 0.358402056802064, 0.3024309248682, -0.394114506412192, 
0.788140622823556, 0.67070382675052, -0.949180809687611, 0.0361357384849679
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```